# Transfer data to http server from Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I am new to Python as well as the Raspberry Pi. I have just created a program.

```py
Import requests
cpuseriel ="000000000000000"
try:
 f= open ('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r')
for line in f:
      if line[0:6] == 'serial' :
             cpuserial = line[10:26]
f.close()
except:
      cpuserial = "ERROR000000000"
url= 'https://httpbin.org/router_connections/new?router_id='
dt = requests.post(url, data=cpuserial)
if dt.status_code == 200:
          print('OK')
else:
     print(dt. text)
```

In `dt = requests.post(url, data=cpuserial)`, I want to send data to https server but I'm receiving name 'requests' is not defined error.

---

I have installed the requests  module .

Comment: Did you install the requests module? `sudo apt-get install python-requests`. The `Import` should also start with a lowercase I. Also note that `cpuseriel` is something different than `cpuserial`.

Comment: I have correct all the error but still it shows the error in dt line .

Comment: Error- requests.exceptions.ConnectionError : HTTPSConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with url : / test-post.php/new?router_id= :Failed to establish a new connection: connection timed out

Comment: This looks like a server error, where you want to post to. When debugging http(s) requests, the website https://requestb.in/ is handy. You can generate an url there that allows you to test scripts against. Also do note that `/proc/cpuinfo` contains tabs (and not the word _serial_ on a typical output)

Comment: I can solve my error problem but still it shows the syntax error: unexpected indent in line 2 , cpuserial = "000000000000000"

Comment: The language python is strict in it's identation, thereby forcing more readable code. Please update your question with your latest version (including idents).

Comment: It should be `import requests`, not `Import requests`, which is an `invalid error`.

Comment: I can correct my import request but still they get error in line 2

Comment: If I'm sending data to http server using GET request . so, how can I write a python code for it

Comment: I write this program and my      url =  'http://10.10.456/test-post.php/' but this can't bhi show any output on server this shows only - Array { }.                                              I cant understand what is error and why the cant send the data.

Comment: What kind of  data will be send to http server using post method .